# No sound through the onboard sound card in Ubuntu 10.4

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, audio

I use an ASUS M4A78/EM/1394 motherboard with an AMD quad core CPU. The motherboard has on-board 5.1 sound card. I also have a Sound Blaster Audigy PCI sound card. The system has Windows 7 and Ubuntu Linux 10.4 installed in two separate partitions.

The Sound Blaster is connected to 5.1 speakers while the internal sound device is linked to the front panel audio jack which I connect my headphones to.

When I boot to Windows 7, the Control Panel gives me the freedom to make any one of the two my default audio device depending upon whether I need to use the headphones or the 5.1 speaker system. The quality of sound through speakers may not match the quality of the SB 5.1 but it is acceptable.

The hardware and software installed for both devices (under Windows) is okay.

**The problem arises only when I boot to Linux which was installed recently. Here the SB card is functional but I can't get any sound output through the onboard sound card.**

I've worked extensively on Windows and Unix but am new to Linux and would appreciate any help to get the onboard sound-card to function. I've gone through some available information/hints on the net. These required me to run some commands interactively; the output of these diagnostic tests is appended (if it is of any help). If any more information is needed I would be only glad to provide.

The command is in bold characters and what follows is the output.

**aplay -l**

```
// this is the List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices
card 0: SB [HDA ATI SB], device 0: ALC887 Analog [ALC887 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: SB [HDA ATI SB], device 1: ALC887 Digital [ALC887 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: CA0106 [CA0106], device 0: ca0106 [CA0106]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: CA0106 [CA0106], device 1: ca0106 [CA0106]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: CA0106 [CA0106], device 2: ca0106 [CA0106]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: CA0106 [CA0106], device 3: ca0106 [CA0106]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 3: ATI HDMI [ATI HDMI]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

**lspci -v**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] RS780 Host Bridge
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 82f1
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:01.0 PCI bridge: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. RS880 PCI to PCI bridge (int gfx)
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 64
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=64
    I/O behind bridge: 0000c000-0000cfff
    Memory behind bridge: fbb00000-fbcfffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000d0000000-00000000dfffffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:07.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] RS780 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 3)
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: fbd00000-fbdfffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:0a.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] RS780 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 5)
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000d000-0000dfff
    Memory behind bridge: fbe00000-fbefffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:11.0 SATA controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB700/SB800 SATA Controller [IDE mode] (prog-if 01)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8389
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 28
    I/O ports at b000 [size=8]
    I/O ports at a000 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 9000 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 8000 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 7000 [size=16]
    Memory at fbaffc00 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

00:12.0 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB700/SB800 USB OHCI0 Controller (prog-if 10)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8389
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 16
    Memory at fbafe000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Kernel driver in use: ohci_hcd

00:12.1 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB700 USB OHCI1 Controller (prog-if 10)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8389
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 16
    Memory at fbafd000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Kernel driver in use: ohci_hcd

00:12.2 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB700/SB800 USB EHCI Controller (prog-if 20)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8389
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 17
    Memory at fbaff800 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd

00:13.0 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB700/SB800 USB OHCI0 Controller (prog-if 10)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8389
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 18
    Memory at fbafc000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Kernel driver in use: ohci_hcd

00:13.1 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB700 USB OHCI1 Controller (prog-if 10)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8389
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 18
    Memory at fbafb000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Kernel driver in use: ohci_hcd

00:13.2 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB700/SB800 USB EHCI Controller (prog-if 20)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8389
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 19
    Memory at fbaff400 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd

00:14.0 SMBus: ATI Technologies Inc SBx00 SMBus Controller (rev 3c)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8389
    Flags: 66MHz, medium devsel
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: i2c-piix4

00:14.1 IDE interface: ATI Technologies Inc SB700/SB800 IDE Controller (prog-if 8a [Master SecP PriP])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8389
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 16
    I/O ports at 01f0 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 03f4 [size=1]
    I/O ports at 0170 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 0374 [size=1]
    I/O ports at ff00 [size=16]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pata_atiixp
    Kernel modules: pata_atiixp

00:14.2 Audio device: ATI Technologies Inc SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 837b
    Flags: bus master, slow devsel, latency 64, IRQ 16
    Memory at fbaf4000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: HDA Intel
    Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel

00:14.3 ISA bridge: ATI Technologies Inc SB700/SB800 LPC host controller
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8389
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0

00:14.4 PCI bridge: ATI Technologies Inc SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge (prog-if 01)
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 64
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=64
    I/O behind bridge: 0000e000-0000efff
    Memory behind bridge: fbf00000-fbffffff

00:14.5 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB700/SB800 USB OHCI2 Controller (prog-if 10)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8389
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 18
    Memory at fbafa000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Kernel driver in use: ohci_hcd

00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K10 [Opteron, Athlon64, Sempron] HyperTransport Configuration
    Flags: fast devsel
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K10 [Opteron, Athlon64, Sempron] Address Map
    Flags: fast devsel

00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K10 [Opteron, Athlon64, Sempron] DRAM Controller
    Flags: fast devsel

00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K10 [Opteron, Athlon64, Sempron] Miscellaneous Control
    Flags: fast devsel
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K10 [Opteron, Athlon64, Sempron] Link Control
    Flags: fast devsel

01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc Radeon HD 3200 Graphics
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 82f1
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    Memory at d0000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at c000 [size=256]
    Memory at fbcf0000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Memory at fbb00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
    Kernel modules: radeon

01:05.1 Audio device: ATI Technologies Inc RS780 Azalia controller
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 82f1
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
    Memory at fbce8000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: HDA Intel
    Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel

02:00.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): JMicron Technology Corp. IEEE 1394 Host Controller (prog-if 10)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8313
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
    Memory at fbdff800 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Memory at fbdff400 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128]
    Memory at fbdff000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128]
    Memory at fbdfec00 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ohci1394
    Kernel modules: firewire-ohci, ohci1394

03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8385
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 27
    I/O ports at d800 [size=256]
    Memory at fbeff000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Expansion ROM at fbec0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169

04:06.0 Multimedia audio controller: Creative Labs CA0106 Soundblaster
    Subsystem: Creative Labs Device 1004
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 20
    I/O ports at ec00 [size=32]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: CA0106
    Kernel modules: snd-ca0106

04:07.0 Communication controller: Conexant Systems, Inc. HSF 56k HSFi Modem (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Conexant Systems, Inc. Device 2004
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 10
    Memory at fbff0000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    I/O ports at a880 [size=8]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
```

**aplay -L**

```
pulse
    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
front:CARD=SB,DEV=0
    HDA ATI SB, ALC887 Analog
    Front speakers
surround40:CARD=SB,DEV=0
    HDA ATI SB, ALC887 Analog
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=SB,DEV=0
    HDA ATI SB, ALC887 Analog
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=SB,DEV=0
    HDA ATI SB, ALC887 Analog
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=SB,DEV=0
    HDA ATI SB, ALC887 Analog
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=SB,DEV=0
    HDA ATI SB, ALC887 Analog
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=SB,DEV=0
    HDA ATI SB, ALC887 Digital
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
front:CARD=CA0106,DEV=0
    CA0106, CA0106
    Front speakers
rear:CARD=CA0106,DEV=0
    CA0106, CA0106
    Rear speakers
center_lfe:CARD=CA0106,DEV=0
    CA0106, CA0106
    Center and Subwoofer speakers
side:CARD=CA0106,DEV=0
    CA0106, CA0106
    Side speakers
surround40:CARD=CA0106,DEV=0
    CA0106, CA0106
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=CA0106,DEV=0
    CA0106, CA0106
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=CA0106,DEV=0
    CA0106, CA0106
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=CA0106,DEV=0
    CA0106, CA0106
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=CA0106,DEV=0
    CA0106, CA0106
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=CA0106,DEV=0
    CA0106, CA0106
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=HDMI
    HDA ATI HDMI, ATI HDMI
    HDMI Audio Output
```

Comment: Have you checked out: System -> Preferences -> Sound

Comment: I have a Sound Blaster PCI 128 card in a PC I built with an AsRock motherboard and it works great if I boot and run Ubuntu 10.04 from a USB drive. If I install Ubuntu on the hard drive, I get no sound. The machine is a dual-booter with XP and the sound from XP is great. Maybe you should try booting from a USB drive to see if your Sound Blaster card will work?